# Add sum formula based on change in cell contents

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data that uses "major tasks" and "sub tasks". I would like to subtotal the major task based on the sub task ID values. Every time I add rows if I don't add in the middle of the section the sum formula doesn't get updated. Is there a code that can update the sum for me?

Here is an example of my data. Let's say I add a row between row 4 & 5 and the task ID is "1.4" I want my sum formula in B2 to update.

[image]

Perhaps I can set the "B" column to insert a sum formula with `worksheetfuncion.left`?

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:A15")

For Each r In rng
    If Left(r, 1) = Left(r.Offset(-1), 1) Then
        r.Offset(0, 5) = worksheetfunction.Sum( NEED HELP HERE
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

EDITED QUESTION:

I want to run a code that adds the sum formula in column B whenever there is a change in the ID parent. i.e. B2 would `=SUM(A3:A4)` AND B5 would `=SUM(A6:A8)`

SOLVED:

figured it out but this question is on hold.

Working code is here:

```
Sub subTotals()
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim list As String

Set rng = Range("A2:A15")
'loops reverse order
For lngCounter = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    'uses left function to compare ID with one above. if it's the same it will add to string list
    If Left(rng(lngCounter), 1) = Left(rng(lngCounter).Offset(-1), 1) Then
        list = list & "," & rng(lngCounter).Offset(, 1).Address
    'if first character of ID is different it will sum entier list of addresses
    Else
        rng(lngCounter).Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=Sum(" & list & ")"
        list = vbNullString
    End If
Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and rethink how you are organizing this data.  What are these numbers?  Why are you inserting rows?  Instead of trying to create code to deal with poorly organized data, it's better to look at the big picture and organize your data in a more "standard" way.  That could mean multiple tables. that could mean only adding data to the bottom, etc.  If you want help with VBA Code then you need to have already written something to show that you've made an effort, and where it's going wrong.  See [mcve] as well as [ask] and also [help/on-topic].  Look into `SUMIFS`

Comment: @ashleedawg thank you for the response, but I am unable to reorganize the data since I do not control the format. the code will be part of a larger module. I am looking for a starting point since I don't know where to start. Please don't downvote my question just because you disagree. I would like to keep visibility just in case someone else has a response that can help.

Comment: where you have `SUM(B11:B14)` for example, don't you mean `SUM(B12:15)`?

Comment: Mike, you were given a starting point; specifically sumif or sumifs.

Comment: You control the format enough to insert rows?  If it's "**going to**" be a part of something larger then you need to get organized ***now*** or else you're going to have serious problems later.  I didn't downvote because I disagreed - if you read the links that I posted you will see exactly why I downvoted.  You can always [edit] your post so that you include the information necessary in a good question including showing an attempt at solving this yourself, and you can re-gain votes.  **Please see the links above.**

Comment: @Alan yes, sorry typo

Comment: In that case, the`SUMIF` tip (and a further hint, `LEFT`) would work for you. Have a go.

Comment: @Alan i started some code and added to my big edit. i was hoping that if a major task doesn't exit prior to added the new rows the code string would add the sum. any ideas? i used the `left` function by not sure how to command the `sum` function

Comment: @Jeeped thank you for this. i added my idea for the code to the big edit. any ideas on how to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in C2 and fill down.

[image]

Comment: thank you for this formula. I was able to figure out the code for adding subtotals. i posted in a big edit if you're interested.